# Always coming Undefined if i define sDashboard.js

Tags: requirejs

I'm using sDashboard for my application, when i try to create a module using the requirejs, i always get **undefined**.

This sDashboard is available at the github.

https://github.com/ModelN/sDashboard

My Config File.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8090/module-require_dashboard/js/',
    paths: {
        jquery:'lib/jquery.min',
        mockjax:'lib/jquery.mockjax',
        jqueryui: 'lib/jquery-ui.min',
        Flotr:'lib/flotr2/flotr2',
        sDashboard:'lib/jquery-sDashboard'
    },
    shim: { //add the dependencies that should be loaded synchronously        
        'jqueryui': ['jquery'],
        'timepicker': ['jqueryui'],
        'mockjax': ['jquery']
    }
});
```

The sDashBoard widget js

https://github.com/ModelN/sDashboard

part of js file of sDashboard for your reference.

```
( function(factory) {"use strict";
        if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            // Register as an AMD module if available...
             define(['jquery', 'Flotr'], factory);
        } else {
            // Browser globals for the unenlightened...
            factory($, Flotr);
        }
    }(function($, Flotr) {"use strict";

        $.widget("mn.sDashboard", {
            version : "2.5",
            options : {
                dashboardData : [],
                widgetWidth :400
            },
```

When i use the define to used the sDashboard in Dashboard.js file, i always get the undefined for the sDashboard.

```
define(['jquery','jqueryui','sDashboard'], function(JQuery,jqueryui,sDashboard){
    console.log(sDashboard);    
});
```

I don't know what mistake i'm making, please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sDashboard is a jQuery *plugin*. When you load a jQuery plugin it installs itself on the `jQuery` object. The fact that a jQuery plugin is being loaded in RequireJS changes nothing to this. So usually such plugins, when loaded in a AMD environment (like RequireJS) do not return anything from their factory function. So if you try to examine the module, you find `undefined`. This is perfectly normal, and not a sign that it is not loaded properly. You have to test for the existence of the plugin on the `jQuery` object.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryui', 'sDashboard'], function(jQuery, jqueryui) {
    console.log(jQuery.sDashboard);    
});
```

You do not need to have a parameter that corresponds to `"sDashboard"` in the call back because that would be useless. (Of course if you were to have other dependencies after `"sDashboard"`, you'd have to have a placeholder for it in the parameter list or the other parameters after where it should be would get wrong values.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing as you said, but still i get the same problem. I have a working code in the jsfiddle. jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9hbQZ/. Could you please check it, whether it is fine.

Comment: You had errors in there that have nothing to do with RequireJS. You called ``requirejs`` rather than ``require``. You also had no element corresponding to ``#test``. See http://jsfiddle.net/lddubeau/9hbQZ/3/

Comment: Some thing went wrong in saving sry. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/9hbQZ/14/. $.sDashboard still show me undefined.

Comment: You did not use the code I've shown in my answer. You have to **request** the ``"sDashboard"`` module so that it **loads**. You don't have to have a corresponding parameter for it in the parameters to the callback. (There are also problems in this fiddle with loading resources: you ask jsfiddle to load things and then ask RequireJS to load them again.)